# Какой вариант выбрать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Из 95 объектов деревянного зодчества состояние 14 оценивается как неудовлетворительное. (Или: Из 95 объектов деревянного зодчества состояния 14-ти оцениваются как неудовлетворительные.)

Comment: А где же третий и четвёртый варианты: "Из 95-ти объектов деревянного зодчества состояние 14-ти оценивается как неудовлетворительное" и "Из 95-ти объектов деревянного зодчества состояние 14 оценивается как неудовлетворительное". Если вы способ написания выбираете случайным способом, то необходимо рассмотреть все возможные варианты!

Comment: @Сибиряк Кроме наращения, есть ещё и ед. / мн. число.

Answer (score 2):

> Состояние 14 из 95 объектов деревянного зодчества оценивается как
>   неудовлетворительное.

(наращение окончаний применяется только к цифрам *порядковых* числительных)

Answer (score 1):

Если в предложении ничего не изменять, то первый вариант правильный:

**Из 95 объектов деревянного зодчества состояние 14 оценивается как неудовлетворительное.**

1. **95** и **14** – это [**количественные числительные**](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/675-342_razryady_chislitelnyh_po_znacheniyu_i_ih_sklonenie_pravopisanie_chislitelnyh.html), которые обозначают количество предметов при счёте (два стола, сто рублей, 14 объектов) или отвлечённое число (два, сто) и отвечают на вопрос "сколько?".
   Буквенные окончания (наращения) используются только для записи порядковых числительных.
2. *Состояние 14 оценивается как неудовлетворительное* – необходимо единственное число.
   Объектов – 14, а состояние у них одно – неудовлетворительное.
3. Из 95 объектов деревянного зодчества 14 [объектов] оцениваются как нуждающиеся в реставрации (мн. число).

Answer (score 0):

Если в предложении ничего не изменять, то оно останется очень неудачным. Буквенное наращение использовать нельзя. "Состояние 14" можно понять и как "состояние четырнадцать". Если не хотите писать словами, то нужен "ориентир", указывающий на падежное окончание. Используйте вариант, предложенный Alex_ander: **Состояние 14 из 95 объектов**.